# Finding and generating an Anova table

Tags: c#, performance, .net

I would like to optimize the code to be efficient. Basically the code finds and generates an Anova table with the p-value also computed.

I am inputting a text file with data delimited with commas.

**This is the main function that calls the methods in the library file:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace OneWayAnovaTable
{
public partial class OneWayAnovaTable : Form
{
    public OneWayAnovaTable()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static string TSS, ESS, TotSS, TDF, EDF, TotDF, TMS, EMS, F, p;

    private  void ReadFile()
    {
        List<List<double>> numbers = new List<List<double>>();   

        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"data.txt"))
        {
            var list = new List<double>();
            foreach (string s in line.Split(new[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                double i;
                if (Double.TryParse(s, out i))
                {
                    list.Add(i);
                }
            }
            numbers.Add(list);
        }

        double[] rowTotal = new double[numbers.Count];
        double[] squareRowTotal = new double[numbers.Count];
        double[] rowMean = new double[numbers.Count];
        int totalElements = 0;
        int[] totalInRow = new int[numbers.Count()];
        double grandTotalMean = 0;
        double grandMean = 0;
        double grandTotal=0;


        for (int row = 0; row < numbers.Count; row++)
        {
            var values = numbers[row].ToArray();

            rowTotal[row] = values.Sum();
            squareRowTotal[row] = values.Select(v => v * v).Sum();
            rowMean[row] = rowTotal[row] / values.Length;
            totalInRow[row] += values.Length;
            totalElements += totalInRow[row];
            grandTotalMean += rowMean[row];
            grandMean += rowMean[row]/numbers.Count;

        }

        for (int j=0; j<rowTotal.Length; j++)
        {
            grandTotal += rowTotal[j];
        }

        double sumOfSquares = OneWayAnovaClassLibrary.OneWayAnova.totalSumOfSquares(squareRowTotal, grandTotal, totalElements);
        double treatmentSumOfSquares = OneWayAnovaClassLibrary.OneWayAnova.treatmentSumOfSquares(rowTotal, totalInRow, grandTotal, totalElements);
        double errorSumOfSquares = OneWayAnovaClassLibrary.OneWayAnova.errorSumOfSquares(sumOfSquares, treatmentSumOfSquares);
        double meanTreatmentSumOfSquares = OneWayAnovaClassLibrary.OneWayAnova.meanTreatmentSumOfSquares(treatmentSumOfSquares, totalInRow);
        double meanErrorSumOfSquares = OneWayAnovaClassLibrary.OneWayAnova.meanErrorSumOfSquares(errorSumOfSquares, (numbers.Count-1), (totalElements-1));
        double fStatistic = OneWayAnovaClassLibrary.OneWayAnova.testStatistic(meanTreatmentSumOfSquares, meanErrorSumOfSquares);
        double pValue = OneWayAnovaClassLibrary.OneWayAnova.pValue(fStatistic, (numbers.Count - 1), (totalElements - (numbers.Count-1)));


        TSS = treatmentSumOfSquares.ToString();
        ESS = errorSumOfSquares.ToString();
        TotSS = sumOfSquares.ToString();
        TDF = (numbers.Count() - 1).ToString();
        EDF = (totalElements - numbers.Count()).ToString();
        TotDF = (totalElements - 1).ToString();
        TMS = meanTreatmentSumOfSquares.ToString();
        EMS = meanErrorSumOfSquares.ToString();
        F = fStatistic.ToString();
        p = pValue.ToString();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReadFile();
        display();        
    }

    private void display()
    {
        textBoxTSS.Text = TSS;
        textBoxESS.Text = ESS;
        textBoxTotSS.Text = TotSS;
        textBoxTDF.Text = TDF;
        textBoxEDF.Text = EDF;
        textBoxTotDF.Text = TotDF;
        textBoxTMS.Text = TMS;
        textBoxEMS.Text = EMS;
        textBoxF.Text = F;
        textBoxp.Text = p;
    }
}
}
```

**The library file is here:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace OneWayAnovaClassLibrary
{
public class OneWayAnova
{
    public static double totalSumOfSquares(double[] squareRowTotal, double grandTotal, int totalOfAllElements)
    {
        double sumOfSquares = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < squareRowTotal.Length; i++)
        {
            sumOfSquares += squareRowTotal[i];
        }
        sumOfSquares = sumOfSquares - (grandTotal * grandTotal / totalOfAllElements);
        return sumOfSquares;
    }

    public static double treatmentSumOfSquares(double[] rowTotal, int[] totalInRow, double grandTotal, int totalOfAllElements)
    {
        double treatmentSumOfSquares = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalInRow.Length; i++)
        {
            treatmentSumOfSquares += rowTotal[i] * rowTotal[i] / totalInRow[i];
        }
        treatmentSumOfSquares = treatmentSumOfSquares - (grandTotal * grandTotal / totalOfAllElements);
        return treatmentSumOfSquares;
    }

    public static double errorSumOfSquares(double sumOfSquares, double treatmentSumOfSquares)
    {
        double errorSumOfSquares = 0;
        return errorSumOfSquares = sumOfSquares - treatmentSumOfSquares;
    }

    public static double meanTreatmentSumOfSquares(double errorSumOfSquares, int[] totalInRow)
    {
        double meanTreatmentSumOfSquares = 0;
        return meanTreatmentSumOfSquares = errorSumOfSquares / (totalInRow.Length - 1);
    }

    public static double meanErrorSumOfSquares(double errorSumOfSquares, int a, int b)
    {
        double meanErrorSumOfSquares = 0;
        meanErrorSumOfSquares = errorSumOfSquares / (double)(b - a);
        return meanErrorSumOfSquares;
    }

    public static double testStatistic(double meanTreatmentSumOfSquares, double meanErrorSumOfSquares)
    {
        return (meanTreatmentSumOfSquares / meanErrorSumOfSquares);
    }

    public static double pValue(double fStatistic, int degreeNum, int degreeDenom)
    {
        double pValue = 0;
        pValue = integrate(0, fStatistic, degreeNum, degreeDenom);

        return pValue;

    }

    public static double integrate(double start, double end, int degreeFreedomT, int degreeFreedomE)
    {
        int iterations = 100000;
        double x, dist, sum = 0, sumT = 0;
        dist = (end - start) / iterations;
        for (int i = 1; i <= iterations; i++)
        {
            x = start + i * dist;
            sumT += integralFunction(x - dist / 2, degreeFreedomT, degreeFreedomE);
            if (i < iterations)
            {
                sum += integralFunction(x, degreeFreedomT, degreeFreedomE);
            }
        }
        sum = (dist / 6) * (integralFunction(start, degreeFreedomT, degreeFreedomE) + integralFunction(end, degreeFreedomT, degreeFreedomE) + 2 * sum + 4 * sumT);
        return sum;
    }

    public static double integralFunction(double x, int degreeFreedomT, int degreeFreedomE)
    {
        double temp=0;
        temp = ((Math.Pow(degreeFreedomE, degreeFreedomE / 2) * Math.Pow(degreeFreedomT, degreeFreedomT / 2)) / (factorial(degreeFreedomE / 2 - 1) * factorial(degreeFreedomT / 2 - 1))) * (factorial(((degreeFreedomT + degreeFreedomE) / 2 - 1)))*((Math.Pow(x, degreeFreedomE / 2 - 1)) / (Math.Pow((degreeFreedomT + degreeFreedomE * x), ((degreeFreedomE + degreeFreedomT) / 2))));
        return temp;
    }

    public static double factorial(double n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return 1.0;
        }
        else
        {
            return n * factorial(n - 1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Quick question:  How much data is expected to be in your file?  In the millions?  In the thousands?

Comment: @davenewza: Data right now in the higher thousands. May be planning for millions of data in the following days to come.

Comment: And the number of columns in each row?

Comment: @davenewza: the number or rows and columns vary and may not be equal.

Comment: Understood, but do you expect the number of columns to also possibly reach into the millions?  The reason I ask these questions is because it is extremely important to understand the data before parallelism (for example, take note of my comment to ANeves's post).

Comment: @davenewza: The number rows will not go to millions, will be in hundreds, while the columns could go to the millions.

Comment: @davenewza: any improvements you could work on?

Answer (score 2):

Some advice:

1. Replace `File.ReadAllLines` with `File.ReadLines` — **ReadAllLines will read all file content into memory before the iteration**, and `foreach` is really designed for `IEnumerable`.
2. Definitely replace `for (int row = 0; row < numbers.Count; row++)`, `for (int j=0; j<rowTotal.Length; j++)` and `for (int i = 1; i <= iterations; i++)` with PLinq as @ANeves suggested
3. Not sure that replacing `foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"data.txt"))` will help you, as it is heavily dependent on disc I/O operations.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Parallel.For](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=608) instead of `for`, and the same for `foreach`.
Example:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt");
List<List<double>> numbers = new List<List<double>>();
char[] separators = { ',', ' ' };
/*System.Threading.Tasks.*/Parallel.ForEach<string>(lines, line => {
    var list = new List<double>();
    foreach (string s in line.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) {
        double i;
        if (Double.TryParse(s, out i)) {
            list.Add(i);
        }
    }
    numbers.Add(list);
});
```

Comment: This certainly could work, but it really depends on the data.  If the inner loop is the expensive part (i.e. it runs through a huge number of costly iterations), then this method may work.  If the inner loop is relatively light but the outer loop runs many times, then parallelizing it might not even be worth it (it could even be slower).  Remember that when using Parallel.ForEach, there is additional overhead spent on each iteration.

Comment: I believe you will need to lock around the `numbers.Add(list)` line OR use one of the Concurrent collections. You cannot safely write to a List from two separate threads.

Comment: This will only make it run slower. Splitting a single string is not an operation which deserves to be on a separate thread.

Comment: @Groo I would really like to know why. If one reads hundreds of lines with millions of collumns (see OP's comment to the question), and splits+parses them into an unordered list of numbers, how can threading make it slower? Is the overhead that big that it is not offset by the time that it takes to do a split and a million parses? I don't see how.

Comment: @ANeves: that's true, I didn't expect the number of columns to be that large, it's usually the other way around. But the main issue is that parsing is actually the simplest (and fastest) part of the algorithm anyway. I would use `File.ReadLines` to load lines sequentially and then process them on the fly, which would give more sense to multithreading. I actually suggested this to OP in his/her [previous question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13834), but I see s/he has returned back to the initial approach.